# C programming Concatenation at preprocessing using ##

Tags: c++, unions, preprocessor

I have code similar to below. The `changename()` macro works fine. 
Assigning value to "pin_harf.(a,b,c...)" works fine as bitwise.

My problem is I cannot assign attribute to `pin_harf = 0x02`. It gives a compile error. Why can I not assign to struct type instance the value at once? Normally struct types take values.

If I try to assign like `pin = 0x02` it works. I can get the value from `pin_harf.b`, which is equal to `1` and is correct.

How does the `#define` work? Could you please explain?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define changename(NAME, STRUCT)\
                volatile union\
                {\
                unsigned char NAME;\
                STRUCT NAME ## _harf;\ //is this the problem? How?
                };
int main()
{
  typedef struct{
      unsigned char a :1;
      unsigned char b :1;
      unsigned char c :1;
      unsigned char d :1;
      unsigned char e :1;
      unsigned char f :1;
      unsigned char g :1;
      unsigned char h :1;
      }bit;
  changename(pin,bit);
  /*pin_harf.a=0b1;
  pin_harf.b=1;
  pin_harf.c=1;
  pin_harf.d=1;
  pin_harf.e=1;
  pin_harf.f=1;
  pin_harf.g=1;
  pin_harf.h=1;*/

  pin_harf =(bit) 0x09;  // the problem is here
  cout << "Pin Harfi: " <<(int)pin_harf.a<<endl; // Complile error
  /*If the string "harf" deleted it takes attribute else there is a failure.

  /*pin = 0x09;
  cout << "Pin Harfi: " <<(int)pin_harf.a<<endl; //this works I get the specified value*/
}
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what you want to achieve. You are creating a `union` with a `pin_harf` member and then attempting to access it from within `main()` without declaring a variable `pin_harf` anyway. It's fairly unclear what you want and/or why.

Comment: Well, you precisely declared "pin" as union with your "struct bit" to use pin to set the whole value, didn't you? Now, why do you try to use pin_harf for that?

Comment: The define declares an unnamed union without declaring any variable of that type. It might work if you compile in C11 mode (For gcc add flag `-std=c11`), but I'm not sure since I'm not up to date in C++ and the reference I found only refers to unnamed structs/unions inside a struct.

Comment: @ Iharob Al Asimi  actually I won't code like this.I am working on STM8S MCU ,so there is an include file which contains the preprocessing part part like above. It changes the struct name and adds some strings and gives it a memory address. It worked not as I thought. I'd like to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code `changename(pin,bit);` expands to the following (with whitespace added for clarity):

```
volatile union
{
    unsigned char pin;
    bit pin_harf;
};;
```

That is not very useful. It would be more useful if you removed the final semicolon from the macro definition as follows:

```
#define changename(NAME, STRUCT) \
    volatile union \
    { \
        unsigned char NAME; \
        STRUCT NAME ## _harf; \
    }
```

Then you could use the macro to declare a variable as follows:

```
changename(pin,bit) foo;
```

And access the members of the union-typed variable as follows:

```
foo.pin = 42;
foo.pin_harf.a = 1;
```

Or you could use the macro to name a type as follows:

```
typedef changename(pin,bit) foo_t;
```

And use the named type to declare a variable:

```
foo_t foo;
```

Comment: @ Ian Abbott thank you. I got the reason. Union type sets the value to the specified memory location and hence it is union, could call it by a different variable name. As you indicated by "foo".